# Read TTL from an ICMP message received via Python raw sockets

Tags: python, sockets, datagram, icmp, raw-sockets

I'm building a traceroute-ish tool to determine the number of hops required for a UDP packet to reach an address using only one probe. To do this, I want to extract the TTL from the ICMP message I receive after sending the probe. I'm doing the following and successfully receiving the ICMP message:

```
data, source = in_socket.recvfrom(d_bufsize)
```

But I have no idea how to turn `data` into something that I can read the TTL from. `in_socket` is declared like this:

```
in_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp_proto)
```

Here, `icmp_proto` is just the protocol number for ICMP (obtained by doing `icmp_proto = socket.getprotobyname("icmp")`).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The TTL is in the IP header, not part of ICMP. So unless this returns the entire IP packet, you can't do it.

Comment: @Barmar: The trick is that the ICMP message includes a portion of the datagram that triggered the error. So by sending out a datagram with a known TTL and then using the included portion of the error-triggering datagram to determine its TTL at arrival, you should be able to determine the number of hops.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the TTL of the received datagram, not the TTL of the sent datagram that triggered the ICMP.

Comment: That IP header is at the beginning of `data`.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry for the confusion! So this is probably a silly question (I'm new to Python and networks), but what I'm asking is how to get the TTL from the header at the beginning of `data`. The documentation says that it's a string, and it looks like a string of bytes... Is there a specific byte I should be looking at to find the TTL?

Comment: Take a look at the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module for unpacking a string that contains a binary structure.

Answer (score 2):

> But I have no idea how to turn `data` into something that I can read
>   the TTL from.

[pyping](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyping) does it this way:

```
    def header2dict(self, names, struct_format, data):
        """ unpack the raw received IP and ICMP header informations to a dict """
        unpacked_data = struct.unpack(struct_format, data)
        return dict(zip(names, unpacked_data))
…

            packet_data, address = current_socket.recvfrom(ICMP_MAX_RECV)

            icmp_header = self.header2dict(
                names=[
                    "type", "code", "checksum",
                    "packet_id", "seq_number"
                ],
                struct_format="!BBHHH",
                data=packet_data[20:28]
            )

            if icmp_header["packet_id"] == self.own_id: # Our packet
                ip_header = self.header2dict(
                    names=[
                        "version", "type", "length",
                        "id", "flags", "ttl", "protocol",
                        "checksum", "src_ip", "dest_ip"
                    ],
                    struct_format="!BBHHHBBHII",
                    data=packet_data[:20]
                )
                packet_size = len(packet_data) - 28
                ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("!I", ip_header["src_ip"]))
```

The TTL can then be read from `ip_header["ttl"]`.